# Use await when working with overloads?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I asked myself which of the two following solutions is better?

I have some overloads on a method because the parameters might be optional.

Version 1: Return Tasks and do not await

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public async Task MyTask(int i, int j, int k)
        {
            try
            {
                await MyStaticClass.MyAsyncWorkIHaveToDo(i, j, k);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }

        public Task MyTask(int i, int j)
        {
            int k = 0;
            return MyTask(i, j, k);
        }

        public Task MyTask(int i)
        {
            int j = 1;
            return MyTask(i, j);
        }
    }
```

Version 2: Await in each method:

```
public class MyClass2
    {
        public async Task MyTask(int i, int j, int k)
        {
            try
            {
                await MyStaticClass.MyAsyncWorkIHaveToDo(i, j, k);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }

        public async Task MyTaskAsync(int i, int j)
        {
            int k = 0;
            await MyTask(i, j, k);
        }

        public async Task MyTaskAsync(int i)
        {
            int j = 1;
            await MyTaskAsync(i, j);
        }
    }
```

Version 2 generates multiple (3) state machines at IL level. Version 1 generates just one. So I think from a performance point of view, version 1 is better, but there might be some pitfalls I did not think about.

Is there some best practice to follow?

Comment: `MyStaticClass.MyAsyncWorkIHaveToDo();` seems to be independent of your input parameters? Did you leave out something for brevity?

Comment: Leave out for brevity. Question is just about to use return instead of await. But I will update the question

Comment: You *don't* need to use async or await if you don't intend to do anything in the method after the `await` call. `await` is used to *await* asynchronous calls. If you don't want to await for them  in your method, you don't need to `await`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for version one. As you already said it uses less state machines. 
You only need await if you do something with the result of the Task or want to handle any exceptions.

**edit**

You edited the question to include exception handling in the method. That is fine of course and it shows that in such case you have to `await` the result.

**note**

I see you are using a static class. Make sure no concurrency issues occur! Do you have any shared state there?

**Further reading**

Some more background reading can be found [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

From that blogpost, when returning a `Task` directly the attention points are:

- Exception handling
- Using the `using` statement
- Using `AsyncLocal`

Comment: So you are actually suggesting "Version 3" which is Version 1, but completely without async/await, right? (To which I would agree and upvote, then)

Comment: Sry I destroyed your code sample because I added try/catch around first call in my question after Fildors comment on the question.

Comment: @VSDekar no problem, I modified the answer accordingly